# Trouble while trying to write formatted text on a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this python script to find the passing grades, failing grades and the average grades of a student and write them on a .txt file but I'm having trouble with the script not working as expected.

Here's the part of code responsible for creating the file and writing the data:

```
avg_f = print('Student: {:10s} Passing grades: {:<10d} Failing grades: {:<10d} Average: {:3.2f}'.format(student_name + " " + student_surname, p_g, f_g, avg))
u_ch = input("Do you want to save? Y/N: ")
while str.isalpha(u_ch)  == False:
    u_ch = input("You can't insert numbers or special characters.\nDo you want to save? Y/N: ")
while u_ch.lower() != "y" and u_ch.lower() != "n":
    u_ch = input("Invalid input. Y/N: ")
if u_ch.lower() == "n":
    print("Arresting the script...")
    exit()
else:
    print()
    barr()
    file = open("Students.txt", "a")
    file.writelines(str(avg_f))
    print("The file was successfully saved.")
    file.close()
```

When I run the script, it generates a .txt file but inside the file, it keeps writing "None" instead of the student information. How can I fix this?

It's probably a stupid question but I'm new to coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [print()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#print) function prints on the console and returns `None`. You assign this return value  to a variable that you then put into the file.

Works.

Change it to

```
avg_f = 'Student: {:10s} Passing grades: {:<10d} Failing grades: {:<10d} Average: {:3.2f}'.format(student_name + " " + student_surname, p_g, f_g, avg)
print(avg_f)
```

so your variable holds the *string* not the retrun of `print()` function.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue but now each time I run the script it writes all the data on the same line of the file.

Comment: @mark add a `"\n"` to the string when you write it into the file?

Answer (score 1):

your first line is broken. function print does not return text that prints. See code

```
avg_f = 'Student: {:10s} Passing grades: {:<10d} Failing grades: {:<10d} Average: {:3.2f}'.format(student_name + " " + student_surname, p_g, f_g, avg)
print(avg_f)
u_ch = input("Do you want to save? Y/N: ")
while str.isalpha(u_ch)  == False:
    u_ch = input("You can't insert numbers or special characters.\nDo you want to save? Y/N: ")
while u_ch.lower() != "y" and u_ch.lower() != "n":
    u_ch = input("Invalid input. Y/N: ")
if u_ch.lower() == "n":
    print("Arresting the script...")
    exit()
else:
    print()
    barr()
    file = open("Students.txt", "a")
    file.writelines(str(avg_f))
    print("The file was successfully saved.")
    file.close()
```